# What is the built-in `#[main]` attribute?

Tags: rust, program-entry-point, entry-point, rust-macros

I have been using the `#[tokio::main]` macro in one of my programs. After importing `main` and using it unqualified, I encountered an unexpected error.

```rust
use tokio::main;

#[main]
async fn main() {}
```

```
error[E0659]: `main` is ambiguous
 --> src/main.rs:3:3
  |
3 | #[main]
  |   ^^^^ ambiguous name
  |
  = note: ambiguous because of a name conflict with a builtin attribute
  = note: `main` could refer to a built-in attribute
```

I've been scouring the documentation but I haven't been able to find this built-in `#[main]` attribute described anywhere. [The Rust Reference contains an index of built-in attributes](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/attributes.html#built-in-attributes-index). The index doesn't include `#[main]`, though it does include [an attribute named `#[no_main]`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/crates-and-source-files.html#the-no_main-attribute).

I did a search of the `rustlang/rust` repository, and found [some code that seems related](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/f52c31840df7ec9c9350baff51a8964b20b5e1ba/compiler/rustc_passes/src/entry.rs#L78), but it seems to use a pair of macros named `#[start]` and `#[rustc_main]`, with no mention of `#[main]` itself. (Neither of those macros appears to be usable on stable, with `#[start]` emitting an error that it's unstable, and `#[rustc_main]` emitting an error that it's only meant for internal use by the compiler.)

My guess from the name would have been that it's meant to mark a different function as an entry-point instead of `main`, but it also doesn't seem to do that:

```rust
#[main]
fn something_else() {
    println!("this does not run");
}

fn main() {
    println!("this runs");
}
```

Rust Analyzer didn't have much to offer:

> [image: a screenshot showing Rust Analyzer's contextual help for the #[main] attribute, devoid of any details]

---

What does the built-in `#[main]` attribute do, aside from conflicting with my imports?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`#[main]` is an old, unstable attribute [that was mostly removed from the language](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/29634) in 1.53.0. However, the removal missed one line, with the result you see: the attribute had no effect, but it could be used on stable Rust without an error, and conflicted with imported attributes named `main`. This was [a bug, not intended behaviour](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/93786). It [has been fixed](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/93753#event-6039261153) as of `nightly-2022-02-10` and `1.59.0-beta.8`. Your example with `use tokio::main;` and `#[main]` can now run without error.

Before it was removed, the unstable `#[main]` was used to specify the entry point of a program. Alex Crichton described the behaviour of it and related attributes in [a 2016 comment on GitHub](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/29634#issuecomment-260497562):

> Ah yes, we've got three entry points. I.. think this is how they work:
>
> - First, `#[start]`, the receiver of `int argc` and `char **argv`. This is literally the symbol `main` (or what is called by that symbol generated in the compiler).
> - Next, there's `#[lang = "start"]`. If no `#[start]` exists in the crate graph then the compiler generates a `main` function that calls this. This functions receives argc/argv along with a third argument that is a function pointer to the `#[main]` function (defined below). Importantly, `#[lang = "start"]` can be located in a library. For example it's located in the standard library (libstd).
> - Finally, `#[main]`, the main function for an executable. This is passed no arguments and is called by `#[lang = "start"]` (if it decides to). The standard library uses this to initialize itself and then call the Rust program. This, if not specified, defaults to `fn main` at the top.
>
> So to answer your question, this isn't the same as `#[start]`. To answer your other (possibly not yet asked) question, yes we have too many entry points.

Comment: Interestingly, as per [this comment](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/84062#issuecomment-825038275) the conflict should no longer appear. But it does.

Comment: @peterulb maybe because of this? [Complete removal of main attribute from compiler #93753](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/93753)?